# I'm using the Enterprise Architect, and I have some problems for reverse engineering in C/C++

Tags: reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

I've been performing a project related with reverse engineering using Enterprise Architect tool. But, it occurs unknown errors when I perform reverse engineering in C/C++ language. the error logs are followed:

```
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\7z\7zDecode.cpp  on line 91.  Unexpected symbol: *   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\7z\7zEncode.h  on line 36.  Unexpected symbol: * 
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\7z\7zHandler.h  on line 46.  Unexpected symbol: public   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\7z\7zIn.h  on line 210.  Unexpected symbol: baseOffset   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\7z\7zOut.h  on line 103.  Unexpected symbol: &   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\7z\7zUpdate.h  on line 74.  Unexpected symbol: * 
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Cab\CabBlockInStream.h  on line 37.  Unexpected symbol: void 
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Cab\CabHandler.h  on line 22.  Unexpected symbol: private    
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Chm\ChmHandler.h  on line 22.  Unexpected symbol: private    
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Chm\ChmHeader.cpp  on line 14.  Unexpected symbol: { 
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Chm\ChmIn.h  on line 208.  Unexpected symbol: PURE   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Com\ComHandler.h  on line 23.  Unexpected symbol: STDMETHOD  
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Common\CoderMixer2MT.h  on line 59.  Unexpected symbol: ISequentialInStream  
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Common\CoderMixer2ST.h  on line 43.  Unexpected symbol: GetInStream  
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Common\CoderMixerMT.h  on line 50.  Unexpected symbol: ISequentialInStream   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Common\CrossThreadProgress.h  on line 34.  Unexpected symbol: const  
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Common\DummyOutStream.h  on line 20.  Unexpected symbol: const   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Common\InStreamWithCRC.h  on line 19.  Unexpected symbol: void   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Common\OutStreamWithCRC.h  on line 22.  Unexpected symbol: const 
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Common\OutStreamWithSha1.h  on line 22.  Unexpected symbol: const    
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Hfs\HfsHandler.h  on line 22.  Unexpected symbol: }  
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Iso\IsoHandler.h  on line 25.  Unexpected symbol: STDMETHOD  
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Nsis\NsisDecode.h  on line 41.  Unexpected symbol: * 
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Nsis\NsisHandler.h  on line 19.  Unexpected symbol: public   
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Nsis\NsisIn.h  on line 136.  Unexpected symbol: *    
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Rar\RarHandler.h  on line 19.  Unexpected symbol: public 
You may need to define a language macro.    
There was an error parsing C:\Users\soo\Desktop\7z920\7zip\Archive\Rar\RarVolumeInStream.h  on line 26.  Unexpected symbol: void    
You may need to define a language macro.
```

Checking error logs, I think most of error was generated by codes to be processed by preprocessor, for example, "`#define`", "`#ifdef`" and so on.

How can I solve this problems ? can the Enterprise Architect reverse codes to be processed by preprocessor ?

I have one more question.

when a file generated an error in a certain line during reversing, I found that Enterprise Architect don't process after that error line in that file.

is there a function that can process continuously that file with skipping that error line ?

Comment: There's a specific site for RE now. Try http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

First off, C and C++ are two completely different languages and EA treats them as such. It appears you are trying to import C++ source, so make sure that you haven't selected C as the source type in the Import Source Directory dialog.

Secondly, language macros are defined in Settings - Preprocessor Macros. Again, make sure you select the right language.

Defined preprocessor macros are skipped, not expanded, by EA during parsing (and you can only specify the macro name, not the right-hand side). So if your code contains a lot of clever macros, they won't be included in the model. If that is unacceptable, run the code through the preprocessor and then import the result, which will now be macro-free.

The relevant help page is Software Engineering - Development Tools - Other Settings - Language macros.

Finally no, you cannot tell EA to continue parsing a file where it has encountered problems. It skips out and moves on to the next one.

Comment: And it doesn't parse modern C++ features very well. See https://www.sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php?topic=37752.0